# get the remaining time of CancellationToken

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

In C#, how to get the remaining time after which `CancellationToken` will be cancelled?

```
  async Task<int> Get(CancellationToken ct)
  {
      // How do I get the time after which ct will be cancelled ?
      // DateTime maxTimeToExecuteThisMethod = ?
  }
```

Comment: What if the `CancellationToken` isn't time-based? You can read through [CancellationTokenSource](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs) to find out how the time-based `CancellationToken` works. Ultimately it comes down to [`System.Threading.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8). Short answer: I don't think you can do it.

Comment: You can have a date time variable declared globally. When you request for cancellation you can set it to dataetime.now and in this method calculate the time difference for now. I think you will get what you wanted.

Comment: You can't do this with the out-of-the-box "cancel timer" built into `CancellationTokenSource`. Your best option is probably to build your own timeout mechanism that performs the cancellation and that you can ask for the remaining time. You could probably build a thin wrapper around `CancellationTokenSource`, and maybe `CancellationToken` as well if you wanted.

Comment: @nlawalker Can you please provide your basic idea of Custom wrapper for this ?